# Doing requests in Python to get an http api call

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to python, http apis and json. I am trying to get the json from an http request found in this api call: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/

If I click that link manually I can see the json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "16578.8", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "13755500000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "277557494906", 
        "available_supply": "16741712.0", 
        "total_supply": "16741712.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.34", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.5", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-3.06", 
        "last_updated": "1513295354"
    }
]
```

but my code does not seem to be able to fulfill the request. It just hangs and does nothing, no error or anything, just hangs. My python code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/')
r.json()
```

Update: The code below works for me, so proves requests are working in my python at least for some sites, but it's not to the site I want:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/')
print(r.json()["ip"])
```

It's to a different website though, just one for testing json. Any ideas why I can't successfully query coinmarketcap? Seems to be working for a user in the comments

Update2:

I have changed the header for the request to match the header of my browser. Someone in the comments suggest I do this because it may be that I am getting block because of the 'user-agent'. I first tested on 'http://httpbin.org/headers' to make sure I was getting the headers correctly. I then made the changes to the request to coinmarketcap, but it still hangs. Below is the code:

```
import requests

chrome_headers = {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Connection": "close",
"Cookie": "_gauges_unique_hour=1; _gauges_unique_day=1; _gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1",
"Host": "httpbin.org",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
}

python_headers = {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'close', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}

python_headers_with_host_and_user_agent_mod = {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'close', 'Host': 'api.coinmarketcap.com', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36'}

chrome_headers_with_host_mod = {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Connection": "close",
"Cookie": "_gauges_unique_hour=1; _gauges_unique_day=1; _gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1",
"Host": "api.coinmarketcap.com",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
}

r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers')
print(r.json())
r2 = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', headers=chrome_headers)
print(r2.json())
r3 = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/', 
headers=python_headers_with_host_and_user_agent_mod)
print(r3.json())
r4 = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/', 
headers=chrome_headers_with_host_mod)
print(r4.json())
```

Update3: In the end I could not get this working for coinmarketcap. It seems to work for everyone else but not me and have no idea why. I found another site called crpytocompare which also has an API, and seems to be more what I'm looking for anyway so I'm using that instead.

Comment: Are you expecting `r.json()` to output something?

Comment: Your code works for me.  Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yeah I think r.json() should print the json? But it doesn't even get that far so forget that line, it gets stuck on the requests.get

Comment: No, I'm not behind a proxy as far as I know. Perhaps my IP has to be from a certain country? I'm in Latin America now, could that be why?

Comment: Unlikely.  If you can reach it via a browser, you can reach it with Python, so long as you can figure out how your browser is configured.  A proxy was a likely culprit for the browser working, but requests not working.

Comment: so just to clarify james, you were able to send the request successfully to coinmarketcap using python? i can use python to query other sites it seems (e.g. ip.jsontest.com) , just not coinmarketcap.... really strange

Comment: Yes James and others have been able to run your 3 lines of code locally just fine.

Comment: I ran both your chunks of code and they both retrieved expected data.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but to cover all: you know that the third line in the first example is not printing anything because the ``r.json()`` is not inside a ``print()``-statement? (Unless you're in ipython or jupyter notebook or similar.)

Comment: thanks thomas. yes, im aware. it never even gets to that line anyway, just hangs. i tried with the print too and still hangs. is it possible for coinmarketcap to tell if a query is coming from someone using a browser, or if its coming from a program like a python script? could it be that coinmarketcap is blocking python scripts only from certain countries?

Comment: many servers block requests with incorrect `User-Agent`. `requests use something like `python ...` but browser can use `Mozilla/5.0. Open in browser [http://httpbin.org/headers](http://httpbin.org/headers) and you will see all headers send by browser. You can use requests with this url too - it sends back all headers as JSON. SO you can compare them. See also [http://httpbin.org/](http://httpbin.org/)

Comment: thanks furas. i have tried that and adjusted my headers to try to 'fake' it's coming from the web browser and not python. see my edit2 above to my post for the code i used. unfortunately it is still hanging when doing requests to coinmarketcap. the requests to httpbin worked fine of course and i was able to extract the headers, its just an issue with coinmarketcap site

Comment: WireShark might help you discover what is happening at the packet level.